# How to enter a multi-line command in bash on command line

Tags: bash, command-line

I am troubleshooting a script and I wanted to manually enter each line, one by one, to find the error.

My script has an if statement:

```
if [ -d dir1 ]; then
    rm -rf dir1
fi
```

So I tried entering as a one line command

```
$ if [ -d dir1 ]; then rm -rf dir1 fi
>
```

I tried Ctrl-D but then get message : bash: syntax error: unexpected end of file

So how do I enter this if statement on the command line?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Short answer: you need a semi-colon after `rm -rf dir1`.

See it in action: enter the `if` block exactly as it appears in the script:

```
$ if [ -d dir1 ]; then
>     rm -rf dir1
> fi
```

After running it, use the up-arrow to call back the last command, it will show you the entire `if` block on one line:

```
$ if [ -d dir1 ]; then rm -rf dir1; fi
```

The shell needs some way to interpret breaks between commands inside the if-block. It can't simply treat it as a single command executed all at once, so the semi-colons serve as those breaks.

Answer (score 3):

Besides John’s answer, which is totally correct but will still end up with you entering a (very long) single-line command, there’s an actual way to enter multi-line commands:

```
$ if [ -d dir1 ]; then
>         rm -rf dir1
> fi
```

That is… just type. Upon Enter, the shell will see that the command is not complete and offer the “continuation prompt”.

But what if the command *is* actually complete, or you don’t want to rely on that? Also possible.

It’s called VLNEXT and usually set to <kbd>^V</kbd>, but if you want to make *really* sure, check `stty -a` output and look for `lnext` in the cchars group (on BSD; GNU stty is a rather unsorted output but it’s in the third line for me).

As an added complication, in *cooked* mode, the Enter key submits `^M` (ASCII 0x0D) but we actually need ASCII 0x0A which is `^J` so you have to press that with VLNEXT.

Then, we can type `if [ -d dir1 ]; then`<kbd>^V</kbd><kbd>^J</kbd>`rm -rf dir1`<kbd>^V</kbd><kbd>^J</kbd>`fi`<kbd>Enter</kbd> and it will run this as one big command. It looks like this in GNU [bash](/questions/tagged/bash)…

```
$ if [ -d dir1 ]; then
rm -rf dir1
fi
```

… and when pressing <kbd>↑</kbd> to check history, you’ll see it actually saved the one-line form with semicola there.

Other shells may differ in how they present it — for example, [mksh](/questions/tagged/mksh) will display it like this during input…

```
$ if [ -d dir1 ]; then^Jrm -rf dir1^Jfi
```

… and if you press <kbd>↑</kbd> you’ll see it saves it precisely like that in the history. If you press <kbd>←</kbd> a few times, you’ll notice that these `^J` there are treated as a single character, because it’s really a control character, not the two characters `^` (caret) and `J`.

So, GNU bash will have the nicer input but transform it internally while mksh has one-line input (and command line editing) but keeps it in the history exactly as typed.

In [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh) it looks like multiline bash while inputting…

```
% if [ -d dir1 ]; then
rm -rf dir1
fi
```

… and this is also stored in the history (like in mksh, but zsh has multi-line input editing and therefore can afford to move the cursor up and down the lines and so expand the `^J` to an actual newline; this has the downside, though, that pressing `^U` no longer kills the entire input but only one subline within).

[yash](/questions/tagged/yash) behaves like 1999’s [pdksh](/questions/tagged/pdksh) in that it inputs with the `^J` on one line (like mksh does) but saves each line to the history individually, so on <kbd>↑</kbd> all you get is the last `fi`, which is probably very much not helpful.

A modern (Debian stable/bullseye) [dash](/questions/tagged/dash) behaves like mksh here.

The modern AT&T ksh93 [ksh](/questions/tagged/ksh) “u+m” is even stranger: upon inputting, it behaves like its cousins from the pdksh/mksh lineage, but when pressing <kbd>↑</kbd> it fetches (only) the *first* line of the command (instead of the last like pdksh did), which is probably also not very helpful.

[tcsh](/questions/tagged/tcsh) is… strange. For <kbd>^V</kbd><kbd>^J</kbd> it shows `^M` inline (but otherwise behaves like mksh except, of course, since it’s not a POSIX-compatible shell, the `if` command will fail with a syntax error), whereas, with both <kbd>^V</kbd><kbd>^M</kbd> and <kbd>^V</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, it behaves as if just Enter was pressed.

```
> if [ -d dir1 ]; then^Mrm -rf dir1^Mfi
if: Expression Syntax.
rm: Command not found.
```

And, finally, the original [csh](/questions/tagged/csh)…

```
% if [ -d dir1 ]; then^Jrm -rf dir1^Jfi
if: Expression Syntax.
```

… has no surprises there. It does not have an interactive way to retrieve history, and issuing the `history` command to show the saved lines gives no output (not even for a simple `ls`), so I believe it needs some setting to be enabled or something (I never used the family of C shells).

Full disclosure: I’m the mksh developer.

Comment: Speaking with regard to `bash` at least, copy-and-paste works, too.

Answer (score 0):

This is shell-specific, but there is a way to take the line you are currently editing into your default editor, where you can edit it there, and then save and exit. Once you do that, it will update the command on your command line accordingly where you can then just hit enter to run the command.

In *bash* the keystroke you want is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> (thats 2 keychords, one typed after the next)

Make sure your `EDITOR` environment variable is set to your preferred editor.